# CMake: Proper way to install boost component libraries with project

Tags: c++, installation, boost, cmake

I'm building and linking a project against Boost shared libraries. Now: How do I put these libraries into the target application's install directory? I need this, because the application is going to be installed inside a container without the proper Boost version.

What I tried in multiple variants is:

```
install(PROGRAMS ${Boost_LIBRARIES} DESTINATION install/lib)
```

But neither this nor any other variant I could think of gives me the actual shared library file names.

Comment: In windows the library names are .lib not .dll if that is what the question is about.

Comment: @drescherjm No, that's not the question. The question is how to properly install the boost runtime libraries used to build a project.

Comment: What I meant was you can use `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` to get the .dll names if you need dll names because you are on windows. You could also use BundleUtilities to collect the .dll dependencies of an executable target. I have used both techniques at times.

Comment: @drescherjm `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` resolves to the imported targets, e.g Boost::asio. That doesn't help with installations.
What I'm looking for is a way to get to the actual files...

Comment: You can loop through the items in the `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` remove the extension and add a .dll extension to get the .dll names when these are import libraries. You can also detect if these are targets and get the full path to each dll  from that in a loop. I do this in my scripts.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer here: https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-March/036053.html

> I think you should be able to use get_target_properties(LOCATION) on
> the  imported targets, and then install(FILES ... ) with the locations
> you get.

...so this might work in your case:

```
foreach(lib_target ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    get_target_property(lib_location ${lib_target} LOCATION)
    install(FILES ${lib_location} DESTINATION lib)  
endforeach()
```

Comment: it does not work, because it copies the `.lib` instead of `.dll` files.

Answer (score 1):

> *This is an abridged summary of the answer to this question.
> For a full transcript, please see [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64264225/revisions)*

**Accepted Answer**

The line of code indicated in the question should work, but that depends on how CMake locates the Boost framework.

Only specific components of the Boost framework have installable runtime libraries. If you need any of these, you must list these components in the FindBoost command of your CMakeLists.txt file.

I've tested this on Ubuntu 18.04 with CMake 3.10 and Boost 1.65 using the minimal CMakeLists.txt below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
find_package( 
 Boost 1.65 REQUIRED 
 COMPONENTS  filesystem system 
)
install(PROGRAMS ${Boost_LIBRARIES} DESTINATION ~/install/lib)
```

Following the standard convention of ...:

```
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ..
cmake .
make
make install
```

... I successfully see libboost_filesystem.so and libboost_system.so installed in the specified location below the user's home folder.

Comment: After downloading BoostBuilder, I suggest editing line 34 of CMakeLists to a newer version (say 71), and updating lines 163 and 164 to the matching URL and HASH.  Also, try replacing the keyword install on line  178 with stage.

Comment: For version 71, the matching values on line 163/164 would be URL "https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.71.0/source/boost_1_71_0.tar.bz2" and 
URL_HASH SHA256=d73a8da01e8bf8c7eda40b4c84915071a8c8a0df4a6734537ddde4a8580524ee

Comment: I'm on Linux and know what libraries I need to include. Right now I'm doing it with hard coded paths to the shared libraries of the build environment. But that doesn't seem like a good solution at all.

Comment: @jpo234 I provided a CMakeLists.txt that works for me.